# Convert date format to appropriate one?

Tags: r, date

I have column filled with date with the following format `09nov1992` and  want convert it to `1992-Nov-01`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a link that will help you to convert the date input to any desired output.
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
vec <- "09nov1992"

format(as.Date(vec, "%d%b%Y"), "%Y-%b-%d")
# [1] "1992-Nov-09"
```

---

An alternative version using regular expressions:

```
sub("(\\d+)(\\w)(\\w+?)(\\d+)", "\\4-\\U\\2\\L\\3-\\1", vec, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "1992-Nov-09"
```